# CKEditor changes character when inserted on my database

Tags: php, jquery

My problem is when I inserted in `DB` with `jquery/aja`x using `CKEDITOR`, i've searched how to get content by `CKEDITOR` and my answer is using:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.recipe.getData().
```

But when typed on my form with UTF-8 likes `"á"`, it changes to a different character and saved in my `DB`. How can I fix that? I have searched and config in `CKEDITOR: config.js` but can't find the result! Please give me some idea to improve that. Thanks !

Comment: What is your server side programming language and what is your database?

Comment: what different character it changes to ?

Comment: server side: i'm using php, and database is mySQL

Comment: in my areatext from my HTML, i'm typing: "nước suối đóng chai" - because i'm vietnamese, using UTF8, but in my DB saved "nước suối đ&oacute;ng chai" :'(, i think the problem when using CKEDITOR.instances.recipe.getData()